# toString() not showing anything

Tags: javascript, json, object, local-storage, tostring

im doing  a project for school. In the project I need to call an homemade toString to show all the keys and values of my constructor. Im supposed to fill a form and store my pc in localStorage.

My Logiciels function

```
function Logiciels(ordiConfigure){
    //I start at one so I dont't get the first input which is text type
    for (var i = 1; i < document.forms[2].getElementsByTagName("input").length; i++) {
        if(document.forms[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[i].checked == true)
            ordiConfigure.Logiciels[i] = document.forms[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[i].value;

    ordiConfigure.Logiciels = ordiConfigure.Logiciels.filter(valeur => valeur !== null);
    return ordiConfigure.Logiciels;
}
```

How I store the pc

```
var ordiConfigure = new pcConfig();
    ordiConfigure.Logiciels = Logiciels(ordiConfigure);
    localStorage.setItem("ordinateur", JSON.stringify(ordiConfigure));
```

My toString()

```
pcConfig.prototype.toString = function() {
    var caracteristiques = "<ul>";
    for (var proprieteOrdinateur in this){
        if(typeof(this[proprieteOrdinateur]) !== "function")
            caracteristiques += "<li>" + proprieteOrdinateur + " : " + this[proprieteOrdinateur] + "</li><br/>";
    }
    caracteristiques += "</ul>";
    return caracteristiques;
};
```

heres the constructor

```
function pcConfig(){
    this.Taille = document.forms[2].getElementsByTagName('select')[1].value;
    this.Systeme = document.forms[2].getElementsByTagName('select')[0].value;
    this.Identifiant = document.forms[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
    //This an array for the softwares chosen
    this.Logiciels = logiciels; 
}
```

and here's how I call it

```
<script>
        document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ordinateur")).toString();
    </script>
```

[picture of the page which possesses the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erfuD.png)

It returns null and I don't know why? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Side note, don't continually do calls like `document.forms[2].getElementsByTagName('input')`. Store it in a variable and use that variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You store the `ordiConfigure` as a JSON string in `localStorage`. The problem is that once something is stringified as JSON, it has no connection to whatever it originated from (such as from a class with a custom `toString` method). Once the JSON gets parsed again, it's just a simple Javascript object made up of key-value pairs and nothing else.

If you want to be able to call your custom `toString` method after retrieving the item from `localStorage`, your `toString` method needs to be available at the time you parse the JSON back into an object. For example:

```
function ordinateurToString(ordinateur) {
  var caracteristiques = "<ul>";
  for (var proprieteOrdinateur in ordinateur){
    if(typeof(ordinateur[proprieteOrdinateur]) !== "function")
      caracteristiques += "<li>" + proprieteOrdinateur + " : " + ordinateur[proprieteOrdinateur] + "</li><br/>";
  }
  caracteristiques += "</ul>";
  return caracteristiques;
}

const ordinateur = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ordinateur"));
document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = ordinateurToString(ordinateur);
```

Another option is to transform the object into an HTML string *before* storing it in localStorage.

(Side note: `document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]` is unnecessary. Better to use `querySelector`, which selects a single element, than to use a method that returns a collection and then select the first element in that collection)

Comment: Do it the same way I did - it's the last line of the snippet.